# Text overlaps tables in HTML email on iPhone Mail app when table cells space-constrained

Tags: html, iphone, email, html-table, overlap

I have an automated system that generates a 'staff schedule' (basically a list of work to be performed that day) which is sent out as an HTML email to staff in the morning.

It renders just fine on PCs but in the iPhone email client (tested on iPhone 5S with IOS 8.0.2, the text elements below the table render over / overlap the table, but this only happens when a word completely fills a cell in the table ("Longerword") in this example.

Looking at StackOverflow has led me to add the following tags so far to no avail:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;">
```

An image showing the problem is available here: http://i58.tinypic.com/2lapobk.jpg

The full HTML (which validates correctly) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
<head>
 <title>Daily Schedule for 09-10-2014 (#10)</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;">
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body style="-webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;">
<h1>Daily Schedule for 09-10-2014 (#10)</h1>
<p><b><i>Sent by ollie</i></b></p>
<hr>
<h2>Lorem</h2>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
<tr>
  <th></th>
  <th>User1</th>
  <th>User2</th>
  <th>User3</th>
  <th>User4</th>
  <th>User5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  08:00
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
   (Ipsum)<br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem Longerword</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem &amp; Ipsum dolor</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  08:15
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem (Ipsum dolor)</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  08:30
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
   (Ipsum dolor sit)<br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem &amp; Ipsum</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  08:45
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  09:00
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b><sup>1</sup>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem (Lorem)</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem L</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  09:15
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem &amp; Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  09:30
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem (Lorem)</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  09:45
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  10:00
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  10:15
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
  10:30
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
  <b>Lorem</b>
  <br>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
 <td>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
<h3>Lorem</h3>
<p>1 (Lorem): Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br></p>
<hr>
<h2>Lorem</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:</p>
<ul>
<li>Lorum ipsum dolor</li>
<li>Lorum ipsum dolor sit</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do:</p>
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
<hr>
<h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing:</p>
<ul>
<li>Lorem (Lorem ipsum)</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone suggest what I can try to make this email render correctly on iPhones?